# Why do I still get Operation not permitted when running maven within intellij terminal?

Tags: macos, maven, intellij-idea

I'm on macOS

From the terminal I'm able to run maven/mvn fine

```
letsun@letsun-mac ais% mvn --version                                               
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: /Users/letsun/Downloads/apache-maven
Java version: 1.8.0_371, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-1.8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "13.2.1", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
letsun@letsun-mac ais% 
letsun@letsun-mac ais% sudo chmod 777  /Users/letsun/Downloads/apache-maven/bin/mvn
```

The chmod 777 should give system wide access to this maven file/binary

Now when I open a terminal within Intellij and try to run a mvn command, I keep getting an "Operation not permitted" error

```
letsun@letsun-mac ais % which mvn
/Users/letsun/Downloads/apache-maven/bin/mvn
letsun@letsun-mac ais % mvn --version
/bin/sh: /Users/letsun/Downloads/apache-maven/bin/mvn: Operation not permitted
```

Does anyone know what the issue is here? As you can see by running which, the Intellij terminal's mvn is pointed at the same binary as the working one.

I've tried re-starting Intellij but that hasn't solved the issue

Comment: https://osxdaily.com/2018/10/09/fix-operation-not-permitted-terminal-error-macos/

Comment: @JeffHolt I followed that(granted Intellij full disk access) but that still didn't solve the problem

Comment: intellij is probably opening a terminal app that is different than the one *you* opened. And whatever *it* is opening for you, that is the thing you need to grant. Or, it could be that you just have to restart intellij after granting access.

Comment: I did restart intellij after granting access

Comment: What happens if you unpack outside Downloads and just try to run it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe it's related to the macOS security feature called "System Integrity Protection" (SIP)?As I know by default, SIP prevents modifications to system files and directories, including some directories in the `/usr` and `/bin` directories.
so move the `apache-maven` directory to a location that is not restricted by SIP, such as `/usr/local`

for example like this :

```
sudo mv /Users/letsun/Downloads/apache-maven /usr/local/
```

then don't forget to update `PATH`

```
export PATH="/usr/local/apache-maven/bin:$PATH"
```

at the end restart IntelliJ and try running the `mvn` command again.

good luck !